# Why sql subtraction two colon

Tags: sql

code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mss.colon1 AS newcolon1, ms.colon2 AS newcolon2, 

                               (SELECT        COUNT(mmm.numbertop) AS Expr1
                               FROM            listtable AS mmm
                               WHERE        (ms.number = mmm.number) ) AS examplecolon1,


                               (SELECT        COUNT(stls.numbertop) AS Expr1
                               FROM           listtable2 AS stls
                               WHERE        ms.number = stls.number ) AS examplecolon2,


                               examplecolon1 -(2 * examplecolon2) from
```

.................

example:

subtraction error  :

examplecolon1 -(2 * examplecolon2)

why solved the problem?

Comment: please provide sample data and expected output

Comment: You cannot re-use column aliases in the same `SELECT` where they are defined.  You need to use a subquery, CTE, or similar mechanism to define the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subquery or a CTE (if your backend supports) to do that. ie:

```
select newcolon1, newcolon2,
   examplecolon1, examplecolon2,
   examplecolon1 -(2 * examplecolon2) as myNewColumn
from
(SELECT DISTINCT mss.colon1 AS newcolon1, ms.colon2 AS newcolon2, 
                               (SELECT        COUNT(mmm.numbertop) AS Expr1
                               FROM            listtable AS mmm
                               WHERE        (ms.number = mmm.number) ) AS examplecolon1,
                               (SELECT        COUNT(stls.numbertop) AS Expr1
                               FROM           listtable2 AS stls
                               WHERE        ms.number = stls.number ) AS examplecolon2
from myTable1 ms
[left\right\inner] join  myTable2 mss on ... ) sq;
```

Comment: AKA _derived table_.